# How to throttle a job in laravel scheduler

Tags: laravel, scheduler, jobs, throttling, rate-limiting

I have a job set up in laravel scheduler which currently takes about 20minutes to finish running from start to finish.

However, I have recently been facing an error where the job get's **'killed'** prematurely and i get an email notifying me that I have exceeded the rate limit of 90 API request per minute.

Is there any way that I can implement some sort of throttle on the laravel scheduler job?

Laravel Project Information

- -Laravel Version 5.5
- -PHP 7.4
- -Hosted on Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Yes laravel calls it "rate limiting" https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#rate-limiting

Comment: Although it may be worth changing how your jobs run if its taking 20 minutes to finish but that seems like a separate issue as it looks like your getting limited by a 3rd party api

Comment: is this only available for laravel 8/9 as there is no documentation for the laravel version that i am using (5.5) 

Based on my understanding of rate limiting, wouldn't it just limit the number of requests I can make which wouldn't really help resolve my issue?

For example, if i need to make 90 api requests but the rate limiter limits it to 10, the other 80 wouldn't be made.

Comment: To add on to that, the job itself doesn't make any API calls unless making queries to the database counts?

Comment: Laravel rate limiting can rate limit whatever you want, you can rate limit a closure and put whatever you want in there. When you say you exceeded 90 requests per minute, what are you referring to?